# Simplify this bash command

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

How to eliminate typing the search query twice in this one-liner (`search for something`)?

```
git grep "search for something" $(git log -g --pretty=format:%h -S"search for something")
```

---

My solution:

Create bash script `/usr/local/bin/git-search`:

```
search_string="$1"
git grep $search_string $(git log -g --pretty=format:%h -S$search_string)
```

Then I can use:

```
git search 'search for something'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the following in a file and then source that file in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function gitgrep {
    git grep "search for something" $(git log -g --pretty=format:%h -S"$1")
}
```

To source it you would just have period filename `. file_with_function`

Then you would:

`gitgrep "foo bar baz"` (Quotes needed, could play with `$@` instead of `$1` if you don't want to use the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

You can make that as an alias:

```
alias youralias="git grep \"$0\" $(git log -g --pretty=format:%h -S\"$0\")"
```

And then call it from shell like

```
youralias "search for something"
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I thought that, according to the bash (alias) man, `There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.  If arguments are  needed,  a shell function should be used.`

Comment: So that little gotcha is why I had a strange feeling that something is wrong while I was typing up my tip. Kyle got it right.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use bash history expansion:

```
git grep "search for something" $(git log -g --pretty=format:%h -S!#:2)
```

Answer (score 1):

While all these will work, if you are also wanting to shorten your base commands for git, just create a file in `~/.gitconfig` and add some aliases.  For example, here are some of mine:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
   ci = commit
   co = checkout
   f = fetch
   s = status
   b = branch
   d = diff
   a = add
   l = log
   g = grep
```

So now, you could issue the following:

`git g "search for something" $(git l -g --pretty=format:%h -S"search for something")`

OR you could still have the git aliases in your .gitconfig file, but also incorporate other peoples bash functions, aliases, etc that were proposed in this thread.

Comment: Alias would be good, but for the whole command. Actually, alias with parameters. Unfortunately I don't know how to shorten this to: `git g 'search for something'` using alias. See update to my question for alternative solution.